# Moving shape along path?

Tags: .net, wpf, interpolation, gsap

I would like to know please, what's the recommended approach out there to do a motion path in WPF ? is there a well-known library out there ? or is it recommended to use WPF native framework ?

I know that interpolation might get complicated when talk about easing in and out, velocities, and etc .. what I want is some thing handy& robust at the same time.

I like to know what's the community is using for coding such a feature, Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an animation which uses DoubleAnimationUsingPath inside a StoryBoard.

There's a sophisticated example here, which will help visually demonstrate some possibilities.

- http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/09/14/AnimatingObjectsAlongAPath.aspx

If you want more control over things like velocities and speed, which might not be achievable by just changing SpeedRatio then you can delve into animation clocks, but might be able to do with a custom easing function.

- http://10rem.net/blog/2009/11/04/creating-custom-easing-functions-in-wpf-4-and-silverlight
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/18/wpf-animations-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Codeplex has a number of animation based libraries that can help you out:

- http://artefactanimator.codeplex.com/
- http://bling.codeplex.com/
- http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/  (has some animation related classes)